# derived class with no implementation file (.cpp)

Tags: c++, oop, arm, cross-compiling

In project I've inherited from coworker, I have base c++ class with header and implementation. For the sake of understanding, I will provide example situation, because the code itself is too big:
**bthidtransport.h**:

```
class BtHidTransport
{
public:
    BtHidTransport();    // constructor

protected:
    virtual ~BtHidTransport();   // destructor
}    // BtHidTransport
```

**bthidtransport.cpp**:

```
BtHidTransport::BtHidTransport
{
}   // constructor

BtHidTransport::~BtHidTransport()
{
}   // destructor
```

This is base class, now we have derived class header:
**bthidtransportfixes.h**:

```
#include "bthidtransport.h"

class BtHidTransportFixes : public BtHidTransport
{
    BtHidTransportFixes(); // constructor
    virtual ~BtHidTransportFixes();    // destructor
}   // BtHidTransportFixes
```

However, in particular project, *BtHidTransportFixes* has no implementation (*.cpp*) file. The project itself builds without errors. If I instantiate new object at runtime from class with:

```
BtHidTransport* createdObject=new BtHidTransportFixes();
```

and *BtHidTransportFixes* has no implementation (*.cpp*) file, what is the order of execution in terms to parent class? I am using **Eclipse 4.3.2 for Windows** (host OS is **Windows 7 64bit Ultimate**) with **ARM DS-5 5.20.2** compiler. There is no implementation of `BtHidTransportFixes` anywhere in the project, I've searched for it in **ALL projects files**. Compiler optimizations are turned off with [-O0](https://static.docs.arm.com/100748/0609/compiler_user_guide_100748_0609_00_en.pdf) flags **explicitly**. Here is assembler listing of build process:

```
;;;107        // Create the BT transport first
;;;108        BtHidTransport *btTransport = new BtHidTransportFixes();
00002a  2088              MOVS     r0,#0x88
00002c  f7fffffe          BL       _ZN16StartupAllocatednwEj ; StartupAllocated::operator new(unsigned)
000030  4934              LDR      r1,|L1.260|
000032  2200              MOVS     r2,#0
000034  9100              STR      r1,[sp,#0]
000036  4b34              LDR      r3,|L1.264|
000038  4611              MOV      r1,r2
00003a  f7fffffe          BL       _ZN19BtHidTransportFixesC1EP9BtHidConnP13BtPairingListPK14tBTM_APPL_INFOPK23tBTM_LINK_EVT_CALLBACKS ; BtHidTransportFixes::BtHidTransportFixes()
00003e  4604              MOV      r4,r0
```

and linker ouput:

```
Stack Usage for BtHidTransportFixes::BtHidTransportFixes() 0x0 bytes.
Stack Usage for BtHidTransportFixes::BtHidTransportFixes() 0x0 bytes.
Stack Usage for BtHidTransportFixes::BtHidTransportFixes__sub_object() unknown bytes.
BtHidTransportFixes::BtHidTransportFixes() 0x0020587d   Thumb Code     0  20730_ram_ext.symdefs ABSOLUTE
    BtHidTransportFixes::BtHidTransportFixes__sub_object() 0x0020587d   Thumb Code     0  20730_ram_ext.symd
```

The size of constructor seems to be 0, what exaclty is executed here? And to simplify out, I've deliberately deleted parameters of constructor (here, in StackOverflow description of issue), is this my bad?

Comment: If there's no definition for the constructor or destructor, the program should not build so you can't run it.

Comment: "The project itself builds without errors." You **should** get "undefined symbols" errors for `DerivedClass::DerivedClass();` and  `virtual ~DerivedClass();`

Comment: @DmytroDadyka I agree, but there are no errors while building, just some warnings related to unused variables, and NOT related to particular issue.

Comment: Perhaps this part of the code is not compiled at all. Try to make changes that are guaranteed to cause an error and compile.

Comment: If what you have builds without errors, then you need to create a [mcve] that replicates your problem *and* builds. Something which we can copy-paste and try ourselves.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: instead of `DerivedClass* createdObject=new DerivedClass()` we have `BaseClass* createdObject=new DerivedClass();`. I have updated the question.

Comment: It does not change anything, the linker will not be able to perform `new DerivedClass()` because can not find  `DerivedClass::DerivedClass()`

Comment: Maybe the implemented is in some other file than **DerivedClass.cpp**?

Comment: @DmytroDadyka is it possible this is some weird feature of **DS-5 ARM** compiler?

Comment: Search for `DerivedClass::DerivedClass` in the entire code base. My first thought would've been "the implementation can also be in `DerivedClass.h`" but I strongly suspect you looked there already, so please rule out that the constructor is defined anywhere else.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I have and had already updated a question, there is no implementation in any file connected to particular project.

Comment: It's a long shot, but: Do you link to any existing (compiled) libraries that might contain the symbols the linker needs here? I doubt that's the answer but who knows.

Comment: @MaxLanghof no, the project is being built every time from scratch, I've checked project files timestamps, file are being created during build process.

Comment: I meant an external library of sorts. Again, not expecting this to be the case (and it probably doesn't even make sense in your case) but it's not impossible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187998/discussion-between-kernelpanic-and-max-langhof).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to particular issue. Build process file (*.inc*) is instructed to replace header file *bthidtransportfixes.h* with patched *bthidtransportfixes.h*, which was not included in project tree itself, but resided in *Windows User Home Directory* and then the missing code itself is copied from patched header to original. If I clean project, the operation is reversed. What a bunch of nonsense, this project is heavily messed up! Here is missing constructor code, taken from patch:

```
BtHidTransportFixes::BtHidTransportFixes(BtHidConn            *btHidConn, 
                                         BtPairingList        *hostList, 
                                         const tBTM_APPL_INFO *btmSecCallbacks,
                                         const tBTM_LINK_EVT_CALLBACKS *btmLinkEvtCb) :
    BtHidTransport(btHidConn, hostList, btmSecCallbacks, btmLinkEvtCb)
{
    #ifdef PROXIMITY_ASSOCIATION_SUPPORT
        // Initialize the observer to NULL
        proxAssocObserver.pObj = NULL;
    #endif
    #ifdef FIX_NEED_DISCOVERYLED_TICK
        discoveryTickEnabled = hidAppConfig.discoveryLedEnabled;

        discoveryTickBasePeriodInMs = 50;
    #endif

    #ifdef FIX_CQ_911035
        ucdConnectRequested = FALSE;
    #endif
}
```

I have created implementation file myself, add it to project, put the patched code in it, remove *.inc* command to include patch, added newly implementation file to build process and it works now like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't have to fail to build. Even though a virtual member function is implicitly used under the one definition rule.

> **[basic.def.odr]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#4) Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every
>   non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program
>   outside of a discarded statement; **no diagnostic required**. The
>   definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in
>   the standard or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is
>   implicitly defined (see [class.ctor], [class.dtor] and [class.copy]).
>   An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation
>   unit in which it is odr-used outside of a discarded statement.

Your tool-chain does not have to warn about it, or fail to build. It can pretend all is well. The program is plain ill-formed in that case. If the tool-chain manages to get around the problem, or not diagnose it until a runtime crash occurs, it's all within the contract.

Answer (score 2):

If a program lacks implementations of declared member functions, there is no execution at all - the linker will not be able to build an executable.

The only thing where missing implementations do not matter is if the respective class is never used. In this case, the linker will never be forced to look for an implementation.

But if your program contains - as you state - the following line

```
DerivedClass* derivedClass=new DerivedClass();
```

the program is ill-formed (and the linker should complain).

Comment: I've triplechecked, there is no **DerivedClass.cpp** in the project and it builds without problems.

Comment: @KernelPanic: Do you get an executable, or just compiled translation units?

Comment: I get working `.hex` file (firmware), which I download to target PCB and it works, however I am curious regarding this particular issue, because I want to understand the code.

Comment: Could you try to turn off optimizations? Probably the compiler optimises away any use of DerivedClass ...